# When does season 9 of Bleach take place chronologically?

Tags: bleach

At first, I thought it was taking place before they went to Las Noches, but Chad used his right arm as the shield Brazo Derecha de Gigante which he only developed in Las Noches.

When does season 9 take place chronologically?

Answer (score 2):

Season 9 of bleach is filler and doesn't take place in canon.

Comment: But what place does it take in the anime?

Comment: You should consider filler to happen in essentially a parallel universe. Typically, all the powers that have been seen so far are fair game in the filler, even if it makes little chronological sense.